# Mounting a ceiling flange to the underside of subfloor

Tags: ceiling, subfloor, flange

I'm installing four 3/8" threaded hanger rods and need them installed in exact positions. The rods will be holding approx. 50lbs total; they are supports for a concealed ducted air conditioner/heat pump which requires supporting at each corner. Manufacturer specifies they should not use struts, but 3/8 threaded rods connected with washers and nuts.

I'm planning on using ceiling flanges to acheive this, but want to install them onto the underside of a subfloor. The subfloor is 3/4" OSB. My ceiling flanges require 1-1/2" wood screws.

Can I add a piece of 2x4 and attach that firmly using four 2-1/4" wood screws and then attach the ceiling flanges to the 2x4?

Here's what it would look like without the 2x4:
[image: Ceiling Flange attached to Subfloor only]

Here's what I am proposing (is this okay?):
[image: Ceiling Flange attached to Subfloor with a piece of 2/4]

Comment: What size and type of fastener you should use is dependent on how much weight or lateral force the flange is going to be subject to.  What are the rods going to be doing?

Comment: 4 rods will be holding approx. 50lbs total. They are supports for concealed ducted air conditioner/heat pumps which require supporting at each corner. Manufacturer specifies they should not use struts, but 3/8 threaded rods connected with washers and nuts.

Comment: The ceiling flange specs state 180lbs holding potential if supported with 1-1/2" wood screws.

Comment: A sub floor should have 2x joists about 16 inches from each other.  Do not know the weight of your duct work, but instead of screwing 2x4s to OSB, would screw them to the joists near by.  For hanging stuff, do not have to worry about the screws pulling out of the OSB.

Comment: Imagine using only the 2-1/4" screws by themselves. Adding the 2x4 does not increase the amount of engagement that the screws have in the OSB.

Comment: Why are you not looking to attach your flanges directly to the floor joists? Your 3/4" subfloor isn't just floating in the air, it's got something holding it up - take advantage of _that_.

Comment: Second the above. Joists, or pieces attached between the joists, makes much more sense. Put the load on something intended to carry load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Your 2-1/4" screws will each have about 1/2" of useful penetration into the OSB. That's just enough to delay catastrophe until your unease about the plan subsides. Then you may see the whole thing come down, along with a nice big wafer off the bottom of your subfloor.

Anchor the two-by to adjacent joists, or run the screws through from *above*. If you're going to rely completely on tension, rather than shear, it had better be substantial.

If you're unable to do either of those (or *along with* either of those), slather the two-by with heavy duty construction adhesive to spread the load and add holding strength.

Comment: Personally I'd bolt rather than screw from above.  A set of nice big countersunk bolts, with nuts and washers on the bottom.  Ideally self-locking nuts (you'll need an assistant).

Comment: Countersunk in 3/4" material? That _might_ leave you with half an inch of support in distinctly layered material. Doesn't sound great to me.

Comment: I work in metric, but M6 in 3/4" would be plenty and give you 15.75mm or about 5/8".  1/4-20 would be a touch more given the different CSK angle. My "nice big" was perhaps misplaced given the loads involved, but I probably wouldn't go below M5.  And with machine screws into wood you don't need to (fully) cut away the countersink - use the fact that wood compresses.   I assumed protruding heads wouldn't work, but unless you imagined the screw heads proud of the surface your "screw from above" has exactly the same problem.

Comment: The head of an M6 or 1/4-20 bolt (plus a washer) is much thicker than 1/8". Wood doesn't compress appreciably in this case, and will mostly happen in the solid lumber, not the OSB. Sorry, but it's not viable as an improvement over bugle-head screws. Fender bolts might work.

Comment: counter**sunk** not counterbored.  Dimension *t* [here](https://itafasteners.com/products-socket-countersunk-head-screws.php). Conical so it really does compress. Washer only on underside to protect surface as you tighten the nut

Comment: Fair enough. You don't often see flathead bolts used with wood, so that didn't come to mind. Countersunk and counterbored are synonymous when referring only to the setting of the head flush with the material. The roots mean the same thing, practically speaking.

Comment: I wonder if it's a US/UK thing.  Here countersinking (in woodwork or engineering) always means a conical depression in the surface, while a counterbore always has parallel sides (the bottom may be flat or countersunk) and is more common in metalworking.  A counterbore can also leave the head properly recessed.  What you call flat heads we call countersunk heads; "flat head" here is a rare term for what's more often an extra low, wide (almost disc-like) head, usually a hex socket head.

Comment: My perspective comes from carpentry, where things are probably not as standardized as in steel fabrication, for example. IMO, a counterbore the depth of a bolt head is functionally identical to a conical countersink for the same purpose. In other words, a counterbore can be a subset or type of countersink. It's all somewhat pedantic, though.